# go routine channel & WaitGroup fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, channel

Can someone explain why I am getting a deadlock when pushing a reply to a channel that has no buffer size indicated?

My test deadlocks when I create a confirm channel this way;
this one deadlocks: [deadlock](https://play.golang.org/p/i8QHCURHFeL)

```
   request := RequestMessage{
        Value:   "make it rain",
        Confirm: make(chan *ReplyMessage),
    }
```

but not when I created as such;
this one does not deadlock: [no deadlock](https://play.golang.org/p/c4XQRQsW1ol)

```
    request := RequestMessage{
        Value:   "make it rain",
        Confirm: make(chan *ReplyMessage,1),
    }
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type ReplyMessage struct {
    Value string
}

type RequestMessage struct {
    Value   string
    Confirm chan *ReplyMessage
}

var requestChannel chan *RequestMessage

func main() {
    requestChannel = make(chan *RequestMessage, 10) // 8 is channel buffer size
    request := RequestMessage{
        Value:   "make it rain",
        Confirm: make(chan *ReplyMessage),
    }
    requestChannel <- &request

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done() // invoke Done on the WaitGroup when finished
        request := <-requestChannel
        fmt.Printf("Got Request: %s\n", request.Value)
        reply := ReplyMessage{Value: "hi"}
        request.Confirm <- &reply

    }()

    wg.Wait()

    reply := <-request.Confirm
    fmt.Println(reply.Value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get deadlock as in case of unbuffered confirm chan there is no reader so the send operation blocks. At the same time you're waiting the goroutine to return (the `wg.Wait()` statement) in the main. And so both the main and goroutine are blocked.

Using buffered chan allows the goroutine to complete the send operation and exit and thus the `wg.Wait()` statement succeeds and main continiues after that.

One way to fix unbuffered chan case is to change the place where you wait for the goroutine(s) to finish, ie

```
reply := <-request.Confirm
fmt.Println(reply.Value)
wg.Wait()
```

wouldn't deadlock as you read from the chan before you block the main thus allowing the goroutine(s) to exit.

Comment: makes perfect sense.  In one of my tests, I spawned 100s of go routines.  Doing a wg.Wait()  works well for that test, and then I go through all the stored confirm channels.  Both of your approaches work.  Thanks.